# How to access a variable from a proc in Tcl

Tags: tcl, proc

I have a test.tcl file that sources another common.tcl file which contains common procs. Here's a sample content of the common.tcl :

```
set top_path  path.to.top
set path_a    $top_path.a

proc x { level } {
  if { $level == "top" } {
    puts $top_path
  }
  if { $level == "a" } {
    puts $path_a
  }
}

proc y {
  puts $env(WORKAREA)
}
```

And here's how the test.tcl looks like :

```
source $env(PATH_TO_COMMON)/common.tcl
x top
y
```

The error I'm getting is that the variables (the ones set at the topmost 2 lines of common.tcl) and even the environment variable `WORKAREA` could not be read (no such variable). No matter if I use `set ::env(top_path)` and try to read it inside the proc as `puts $::env(top_path)`, I see the same error. Any simple way to resolve this ? There are many lines of setting variables that I need to update.

Comment: I don't have time for an actual answer, but read up on the `global` and `variable` commands.

Comment: Why don't you read the global variable in a proc with $::env($::top_path) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question. How about re-write the script like the following? Add global namespace qualifier :: before the variable names. Also add $ before variable level. And use "eq" instead of "==".

```
set top_path  path.to.top
set path_a    $top_path.a

proc x { level } {
  if { $level eq "top" } {
    puts $::top_path
  }
  if { $level eq "a" } {
    puts $::path_a
  }
}

proc y {
  puts $::env(WORKAREA)
}
```